# KnockoutJS custom bindings element has no children?

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding

I'm working on a custom binding that will fetch existing values and insert it into the viewmodel. However, I hit a snag where the element provided in ko.bindingHandlers doesn't seem to have any child elements.

Is this how things work in KnockoutJS or am I missing something?

Here is my HTML markup:

```html
<div data-bind="with: person, useInitValueFor: ['firstName', 'lastName']">
    <div data-bind="text: firstName">John</div>
    <div data-bind="text: lastName">Doe</div>
</div>
```

And here's my JS code:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.useInitValueFor = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $elem = $(element);
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();

        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            var c = value[i];
            var e = $elem.children('[data-bind*="' + c + '"]:first');
            alert(e.length); // This gives me 0
            if (e.length > 0) {
                var a = e.attr('data-bind').split(',');
                for (var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                    var b = a[j].split(':');

                    switch (b[0]) {
                        case 'text':
                            allBindings.with[c](b[1]);
                            alert(allBindings.with[c]());
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

function personViewModel() {
    this.person = {
        firstName: ko.observable(),
        lastName: ko.observable()
    };
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var vm = new personViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

You can also see it here on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dzul1983/XjD3Y/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The init function of the `with` binding copies off the children of the element to use as a "template".  The `update` portion applies the current data against that "template".

So, when your binding's code runs, you are right in between the `with` binding's `init` and `update`.

One solution for you is to list your binding before the `with` binding.

Comment: Is it possible to access the elements that are being processed by the with binding during the init process from my binding?

Comment: Probably easiest to execute your binding before `with`, but if you really had to you would be able to access the copied off elements by using `ko.utils.domData.get(element, "__ko_anon_template__")`